# Google App Engine : How can I access sessions inside a cloud endpoint?

Tags: google-app-engine, session, google-cloud-endpoints

I have developed a standard Google App Engine backend Application for my Android client. Now, there is search functionality in the App and during one request, I plan to return 20 results but I search for more in advanced(like 100) so that for the next hit, I will just search in these records and return. So, I need a mechanism to save these 80 records so that the same user might get them quickly.

I searched for it and found out that we can enable sessions in `appengine-web.xml` but all the session access has been done in `doPost()` and `doGet()` while my code is entirely Google's cloud endpoints.(like Spring)

Another thing is that I would like to persist the data both inside the **Datastore** and some cache(like **Memcache**).

My end goal is storing this data across search sessions. Is there any mechanism that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach here is to provide a code value in the response which the user can send in the next request to "continue" viewing the same results. This is called a "cursor".

For example, you might store the 80 records under some random key in your cache, and then send that random key to the user as part of the response. Then, when the user makes a new request including the key, you just the records and return them.

Cookie-based sessions don't usually work well with APIs; they introduce unnecessary statefulness.

Comment: The robust approach(taken by GAE with Servlets and a lib called gae-sessions(Python)) is use Memcache and Datastore to do lookups. There is not a single lib in Java for that. I was thinking of writing one myself. Relying solely only on Cache might result in loss of data when it suddenly clears off.

Comment: What the cursor actually points to is up to you. My point is that you should use cursors instead of sessions.